# Perl: work with log file

Tags: perl

Please help me, how after every 100 lines,my cycle sleep on 15 seconds, and in a specified time reopen log.

```
open(LOGFILE,$logfile) or die "error";
for(;;){
      if($logfile=<LOGFILE>){
          ......................
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this perhaps

```
open my $log_fh, '<', $logfile or die $!;

while ( <$log_fh> ) {
    print;
    sleep 15 unless $. % 100;
}
```

Comment: @madmax, It's another question, could you please open a new question for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail):

> ```
> use File::Tail;
> my $file = File::Tail->new(name => $name, maxinterval => 300, adjustafter => 7);
> while (defined(my $line = $file->read)) {
>     print "$line";
> }
> ```

If that does not satisfy your needs, see [tell](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#tell-FILEHANDLE) and [seek](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#seek-FILEHANDLE-POSITION-WHENCE).

Answer (score 1):

Just use two loops:

```
while () {   # Same as for (;;).
    for (1 .. 100) {
        open my $LOGFILE, '<', $logfile or die $!;
        if ($logline = <LOGFILE>) {
            # 條件
        }
        sleep 15;
    }
}
```